# Create Block Hide/Show Editor removes empty span

Tags: admin, static-block, magento2.3

I created a new block in Magento **2.3** and want to use `<span>` to place some icons in front of a text.
I clicked on `Hide/Show editor` and pasted my code

`<div class="item"><span class="top-icon fas fa-truck"></span><span class="headline-blue">Item 2</span><div class="text">Reason 2 text</div></div>`

Changing back to the default editor it removes this empty `<span class="top-icon fas fa-truck">`.
If I replace the `<span>` with a `<div>`it will not delete this.

How can I use an empty `<span>` with my icons without inserting a `&nbsp` between the tags `<span>&nbsp;</span>`

---

Edit:

[Sukumar Gorai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/51003/sukumar-gorai) suggested the workaround with a `&nbsp;`but it is only a workaround not a real solution.

Comment: Try <span class="top-icon fas fa-truck">&nbsp;</span>. It should work. I had the same issue and resolved it by adding &nbsp;

Comment: That works/and worked during testing, but fells more like a workaround instead of a solution

Comment: seems like a good solution to me. do you need this empty span? if yes, this is the way to go

Comment: Would be more convinent to use, since I implement all icons with an empty span. @SukumarGorai could you answer the question with the comment you gave, so I can mark the answer as a working solution?

Comment: Are you using with description field or any custom attribute?

Comment: Did you check it in magento 2.2.7. I think its working fine in my default instance.

Comment: Didn't have any Magento 2.2.x installation, only 2.3. `<div class="item"><span class="top-icon fas fa-umbrella"></span><span class="headline-blue">Item 4</span><div class="text">Reason 4 text</div></div>
` this is the entire line I wanted to use on my start page

Comment: @SukumarGorai ---Thanks for the solution...

Comment: @SukumarGorai, can you help me out on this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268769/set-x-frame-options-in-custom-controller-magento2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be issue with editor in Magento. You can try

```
<span class="top-icon fas fa-truck">&nbsp;</span>
```

instead of

```
<span class="top-icon fas fa-truck"></span>
```

I had the same issue and resolved it by adding `&nbsp;`

Hope this helps!