# set x-frame-options in custom controller magento2

Tags: magento2, controllers, http-request, http-header

I have a custom controller with below code.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Service;
class Login extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{
protected $_storeManager;
protected $_customerFactory;
protected $_customerSession;
protected $_addressRepository;
protected $_addressDataFactory;
protected $addressFactory;
protected $customerRepository;
protected $checkoutSession;
private $logger;
protected $cart;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $addressDataFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->_storeManager     = $storeManager;
    $this->_customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->_addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
    $this->_addressFactory = $addressFactory;
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->logger = $logger; 
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {     
    $customerPin = $this->getRequest()->getParam('pin');
    echo $customerPin;die;

}
```

Above code reads the parameter pin from the url and display the parameter value.

**http://www.example.com/test/service/login/pin/6**

This works only if accessed in the same website. Suppose the controller is accessed like iframe, from the other domain. its showing blank screen.

is there any setting to be done? from research i found we need to set **X-Frame-Options** to make it work.

if so how that can be set from controller?

Can anyone look into this and update me the solution please.

Comment: will `$this->getRequest()->getPost('pin');` might work?

Comment: @magefms, not cleared with your comment..yes that will give the param value

Comment: I mean maybe try using `getPost()` instead of getParam and it might work

Comment: @magefms, not getPost() not working, tried it

Comment: I think your endpoint is not giving you the data

Comment: can you post your `webapi.xml` wherein you define the endpoint

Comment: @magefms, no there is no webapi.xml file. just created the controller and calling it from other project.

Comment: how did you setup your route?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92024/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-magefms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a few different versions of setHeader() but the only thing that worked for me was overwriting XFrameOptions.

1. Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<!-- Preference type used, as we can't use a plugin on a __construct function -->
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XFrameOptions" type="Vendor\Module\ResponseHeader\XFrameOptions" />
</config>
```

2. Vendor/Module/ResponseHeader/XFrameOptions.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\ResponseHeader;

class XFrameOptions extends \Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XFrameOptions {

    public function __construct(
        $xFrameOpt = 'SAMEORIGIN',
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request     
    ) {
        // Eg if your iframe controller frontname is 'test'
        $isIframeController = 
            ($request->getModuleName() == 'test');

        // Skip this for the iFrame page
        if ($isIframeController) {
            return;
        }
        return parent::__construct($xFrameOpt);        
    }    
}
```

This doesn't set the X-Frame-Header for the custom controller (eg "test"), but sets it for all other pages, so that your site is still protected against iFrame attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined your **webapi endpoint** like this:

```
http://www.example.com/test/service/login/pin
```

Then you can get the Post Value like this:

```
http://www.example.com/test/service/login/pin?pin=6
```

Otherwise, you will get a blank response when an endpoint is called inside an **`iframe`**.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to include a local environment into a iframe but that is not possible. The outside world can not access http://localsite/test/service/login/pin/6

Comment: no, i am not calling local, just given u the sample example there

Comment: Okay, to set the headers you could try: $this->getResponse()->setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW');

Comment: in first line of execute method?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But did not try it. Got the idea from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/magento-2-sending-a-custom-header-response-from-a-controller

Comment: Tried, but that did not work for me